# Find references to object in gdb?

Tags: gdb, vala

I have the address of an object. Is there any way I can find all references to that address?

I'm working with vala and have a references counting problem. So I'm trying to find where I have a reference to the object that is sticking around.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can set a break point on the appropriate reference function for you object. Each object has `foo_ref` and `foo_unref` that are called to change the reference count. If you set break points on these, you can trace the reference counting.

Comment: My class is defined as `class PanelContainer : Buildable, Overlay` but gdb does not recognize `b panel_container_ref`

Comment: These might get subsumed to the generic `g_object_ref` and `g_object_unref`, which is going to be really annoying.